# Pyxero filtering using the __in

Tags: python, xero-api

I have a filtering on status using pyxero, but I want filtering on two type of status: `AUTHORISED` and `SUBMITTED`.

The actual call is:

`xero_conn.invoices.filter(Type='ACCPAY', Status='SUBMITTED')`

But checking the code there is not `Status__in` available. Is there a `__in` available as in the django orm or I must make 2 calls?

Answer (score 0):

The `raw` option let to do what pyxero is not able to do. I moved the Status in raw and works. Use the [preview](https://app.xero.com/Preview/invoices) to check the raw.

```
xero_conn.invoices.filter(Type='ACCPAY', raw="Status='SUBMITTED' OR Status='AUTHORISED'")
```